# is there a pmml conversion for bnlearn package in r?

Tags: r, web-services, rstudio, pmml

Is there a pmml conversion for the bnlearn package in r, so that bayesian networks can be accessed as an API over the web?

I have seen pmml conversion for some models like decision trees and linear regression, see [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pmml/index.html), but I haven't seen any for bnlearn.

Also, is there any other service which can be used as an API for bayesian network models built in R?

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried this personally but the package r2pmml from GitHub (it is not available from CRAN) may be an option for this. You would then you "Augustus" in Python.